# Heap memory issue while parsing & processing xml file of 3GB with DOM

Tags: java, xml, heap-memory, large-files

Getting heap memory issue while trying to parse a large XML file & then removing some of the nodes based on specific criteria if it met in those nodes using DOM.

Comment: Please post a full stack trace and the code that caused it

Comment: How much memory did you allocate? DOM typically requires up to 10 times the size of the lexical XML (depending on the tag density). You would be better off using a streaming technology for this, e.g. XSLT 3.0.

Comment: DOMScriptXMLParser dom = new DOMScriptXMLParser();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(INPUT_FILE);
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nlist = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
            System.out.println("Child Node Length is ::" + nlist.getLength());

Comment: I tried to run with 6GB memory. But as file size is 3GB, got heap error. Not sure if can use SAX parser as I need to read xml, check conditions & then delete the record from xml or empty specific child nodes. Not getting option to split the file as well.